# TCP transparent proxy with cgroups2: How can I allow TCP traffic only and block all the rest coming from a cgroup?

Tags: networking, proxy, tcp, cgroup

I'm trying to setup a TCP transparent proxy with cgroups2:

```
iptables -t nat -A OUTPUT -p tcp -m cgroup --path test --syn -j DNAT --to-destination 10.0.0.1:10000
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -m cgroup --path test --syn -j ACCEPT
iptables A INPUT -m cgroup --path test -j DROP
iptables -A OUTPUT -p tcp -m cgroup --path test --syn -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT -m cgroup --path test -j DROP
```

Transparent proxy is up and running at 10.0.0.1:10000 (it has to be this address, not loopback).

When I try to access an external address through the proxy I get timeouts:

```
echo $$ >> /sys/fs/cgroup/test/cgroup.procs
sudo -u ${SUDO_USER} w3m 1.1.1.1
w3m: Can't load 1.1.1.1.
```

When I remove the **-j DROP** lines, it works.

My question is:

What kind of rule should I add to block all non-TCP traffic coming from cgroup and let free only TCP?

Comment: tcp connection is a lot more than a single SYN packet.